# opencv) How do I use stereoRectify() with a single camera?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d

for example,

```
cv::stereoRectify( cameraMatrix1, distcoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distcoeffs2, imgsize, R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q, 0, 1.0, imgsize,  &RL, &RR );
```

But with a single camera, it has one cameraMatrix and one distcoeffs.
What should I put in cameraMatrix2, distcoeffs2? Or maybe there are other functions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with stereoRectify, but it does not make sense in the context of a single camera, as it rectifies a pair of stereo images.

Take a look at this : [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~16385/s17/Slides/13.1_Stereo_Rectification.pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7E16385/s17/Slides/13.1_Stereo_Rectification.pdf)